# Facebook JS API not returning email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to setup a new app, identical to another app I setup. The client side code (php & js) is 100% identical except for a different app ID, and the original app works perfectly every time. The permissions are default. The app is set to active. My dev site's domain is added to the app. It actually returns the user object fine, with id/name, but no email. I checked my account I'm logging in with, and both my original app and this one are identical.

My integration is slightly customized, so I copied the actual example from Facebook's dev quick start guide, and same exact thing, no email. I tried different api versions, no dice.

Is this a bug in facebook? Why does one app work, and another with the same exact configuration not? I went screen by screen and there isn't a single difference except domains and app name.

**UPDATE**

Problem is because the old app was created 1 year ago, with API version 2.1. Graph pull request returned email by default in 2.1, and in 2.4 you must specify which fields to pull with the "/me" request.

Comment: Just tested with another device and another account and another connection. No dice. Seems like a bug in FB graph api.

Comment: check out my answer, it´s not a bug, it´s a feature :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since v2.4 of the Graph API, you need to specify the fields in the API call:

```
/me?fields=name,email
```

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: Thank you for saving me having to dig through FB docs. Problem is because the old app was created a year ago, and is old api, new one is 2.4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I needed!

Comment: on some FB login there is no Email in response. Why is that? @luschn

Comment: not everyone got an email, you are actually not required to have an email for facebook login, it is also possible with a phone number afaik